# Make element follow a round container outline on mousemove

Tags: jquery, css, path, geometry

I have [THIS CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/hg21ce45/2/):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="centerdiv">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="follower"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="log">Move the mouse to see the coordonates!</div>
```

CSS:

```
  body, html {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: #151515;
  }
  #follower {
      position : absolute;
      background-color: #F03D09;
      width:15px;
      height:15px;
      border-top-right-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  }
  .centerdiv {
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      position:relative;
  }
  .container {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      overflow:hidden;
      border:1px solid #303030;
      background-color: #181818;
  }
  .log {
      margin: 0px auto;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #181818;
      border: 1px solid #303030;
  }
```

JS:

```
    var documentWidth = $(window).width();
var documentHeight = $(window).height();
var minWindowDim = Math.min(documentWidth, documentHeight);
var newDim = 0.8 * minWindowDim;
$('.container').css({
    "width": newDim,
        "height": newDim,
        "border-radius": newDim / 2
});
$('.centerdiv').css({
    "width": newDim
});
$('#wrapper').css({
    "height": $('.container').height()
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var documentWidth = $(window).width();
    var documentHeight = $(window).height();
    var minWindowDim = Math.min(documentWidth, documentHeight);
    var newDim = 0.8 * minWindowDim;
    $('.container').css({
        "width": newDim,
            "height": newDim,
            "border-radius": newDim / 2
    });
    $('.centerdiv').css({
        "width": newDim
    });
    $('#wrapper').css({
        "height": $('.container').height()
    });
});

var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,
    limitX = $('.container').width() - 15,
    limitY = $('.container').height() - 15;
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    var offset = $('.container').offset();
    var halfContWidth = $('.container').width() / 2;
    var halfContHeight = $('.container').height() / 2;

    mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
    mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);        

    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(e.pageX - offset.left - halfContWidth), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(e.pageY - offset.top - halfContHeight), 2)) > newDim / 2) {

        var ratio = (mouseX - halfContWidth)/(mouseY - halfContHeight);
        var sign = 1;

        if(mouseX - halfContWidth < 0)
            sign = -1;

        mouseX = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ratio,2)*Math.pow(newDim,2)/4/(1+Math.pow(ratio,2))) * sign;            
        mouseY = (mouseX/ratio);

        mouseX += halfContWidth;
        mouseY += halfContHeight;

    }

    if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
    if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;

    $('.log').html("DivX: " + Math.round(mouseX - halfContWidth) + " DivY: " + Math.round(mouseY - halfContHeight));
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    limitX = $('.container').width() - 15;
    limitY = $('.container').height() - 15;
});


// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0,
    yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function () {
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp - 5) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp - 5) / 12;
    follower.css({
        left: xp,
        top: yp
    });

}, 5);
```

As you can see in the fiddle the "mouse follower" follow the mouse being limited by the `.container`. But I want the mouse follower to be limited to the container's round path too. I mean that I want the mouse follower to stick to the container's border even when the cursor is inside the container (Like the radius made by the mouse follower and the container's center to be constant).

And another thing. If it's possible I would like to make it responsive too.